Why does the lunar water need living cells?
The water in Silent Sea has the unusual effect of

increasing in molecular number when it comes into contact with living cells.

A major characteristic of the lunar water is that it actually produces more water than the mass present in the living cells with which it comes into contact—as we see with the experiment with the drop of blood—and seems to not convert much biomass at all, to judge from the conditions of the victims relative to the amount of water—and it specifically needs living matter. Furthermore, unlike the viruses with which it is compared, it obviously does not need a cell's genetic machinery to reproduce.
Most intriguingly, a small quantity of the water even exhibits a distinct "cellular" division process when in contact with living cells, despite not actually having a cellular structure.
Why does the lunar water need contact with living cells, specifically, to replicate?
